# How to use identity comparison in AssertJ iterable assertions

Tags: java, assertj

I am using AssertJ fluent assertions in my code. Example:

```
assertThat(vertexSet).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(v0, v2, v4);
```

Now I need to use identity comparison instead of `.equals(...)`. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Here's what I came up with:

```
assertThat(vertexSet).usingComparator((x, y) -> {
    return x == y ? 0 : -1;
}).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(v0, v2, v4);
```

This works, but I don't particularly like it. Requires a `Comparator` implementation which has a bit wider semantics compared to equal/not equal check I am actually interested in.

Are there better options? Other assertions have variants like `isEqualTo`/`isSameAs`, but I could not find analogs in `IterableAssert`.

Comment: I guess in your example you meant `usingElementComparator` instead of `usingComparator` as the latter would have no effect on `contains` assertions.

Comment: Why do you have to use anything but `equals()` ?